# Rx.Net memory leak

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

An interesting memory leak. Does anyone know why?

```
foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000)
    .Select(async i => i))
{
}

GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes()); // 1036542160

foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000)
    .Select(async i => i))
{
}

GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes()); // 2072860704

foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(0, 1_000_000)
    .Select(async i => i))
{
}

GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes()); // 3109160008
```

Where:

```
static class SelectAsync
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<T, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task<TResult>> selector) =>
        source
            .ToObservable()
            .Select(value => Observable.FromAsync(() => selector(value)))
            .Concat()
            .ToEnumerable();        
}
```

Comment: Your example shows that Reactive Extensions may not be the correct tool for the job, if performance and efficient use of resources is paramount. You could do the same thing with a simple loop and a `List<TResult>` to collect the results, consuming a fraction of the RAM and CPU resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually no memory leak.

`GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes` is a count of the bytes allocated over the lifetime of the process. Every time there's a heap allocation, this counter goes up.

What you want to use instead is `GC.GetTotalMemory`.

If you see the deltas between your test values, you'll see that they're approximately the same.

[image: deltas]

You'll see some minor variations in your tests related to memory pressure.

[image: gc]

Comment: 4,520,216; 8,726,544; 12,921,320; 17,116,528; 21,311,592... It looks like it constantly grows by 4MB.

Comment: I ran with TotalMemory. I'm seeing 183320,
183980,
185276,
186656,
188276,
187964,
185516,
185516,
185516,
186524,
185060,
185060,
188048,
185600,
186080,
etc.

Comment: My process memory profile seems to support that as well.

Comment: @DmitryNogin Could you please tell me what your conclusion was?

Comment: Started using `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. There going to be a fight with updating building process to .NET Core 3.1...